# How can I remove the topbar and the watermark of embedded YouTube video

Tags: iframe, cgcontextdrawimage

I want to remove the topbar and watermark which show in the bottom right corner of the youtube video.
I was trying to apply showinfo but it was depreciate.

I also tried to set a overlay to hide the topbar and watermark but canvas drawimage is also not working.[want to remove this]